# Newbie on Python, statsout not working on Python 2.7

Tags: python

I'm new on Python. I'm testing this code on Python 2.7 but gives me an error.

```
import statsout

def output(data, format="text"):
    output_function = getattr(statsout, "output_%s" % format, statsout.output_text)
    return output_function(data)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\anlopes\workspace\test\src\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import statsout
ImportError: No module named statsout
```

Can someone give me a clue on what is wrong?

Best Regards,

Comment: What is statsout supposed to be? There's no such module in the standard library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your example is from Dive Into Python, and `statsout` is an imaginary module used as an example.  To quote from http://diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/getattr.html :

> For example, let's imagine a program that prints site statistics in HTML, XML, and plain text formats. The choice of output format could be specified on the command line, or stored in a configuration file. A `statsout` module defines three functions, `output_html`, `output_xml`, and `output_text`. Then the main program defines a single output function, like this:

"For example, let's imagine" being the key words there :)  Actually, reading it again I can quite see that that paragraph is easy to misparse...

Answer (score 1):

All examples of "Dive into python" including statsout.py are available for download on dive into python's [site](http://www.diveintopython.net/).
At this day the direct link is [here](http://www.diveintopython.net/download/diveintopython-examples-5.4.zip).

```
"""Prototype multi-output module

This program is part of "Dive Into Python", a free Python book for
experienced programmers.  Visit http://diveintopython.org/ for the
latest version.
"""

__author__ = "Mark Pilgrim (mark@diveintopython.org)"
__version__ = "$Revision: 1.2 $"
__date__ = "$Date: 2004/05/05 21:57:19 $"
__copyright__ = "Copyright (c) 2004 Mark Pilgrim"
__license__ = "Python"

def statsout_html(data):
    """Format data as HTML"""

def statsout_xml(data):
    """Format data as XML"""

def statsout_text(data):
    """Format data in plain text"""
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a PYTHONPATH issue.  Usually files in your PWD/CWD (your current working directory) are automatically on your path.

How are you running this?

I assume something like:

```
cd C:\Documents And Settings\anlopes\workspaces\test\src
C:\Python27\python.exe test.py
```

Assuming that there is a file: C:\Documents And Settings\anlopes\workspaces\test\src\test.py
you also need to have C:\Documents And Settings\anlopes\workspaces\test\src\statsout.py in that directory or otherwise modify your PYTHONPATH to include the location of your statsout module.